# Two lock in amplifiers, almost identical setup, different AC Gain?

Tags: signal-analysis

I am measuring a voltage output of around ~110 uV for two thermometers. Other than the placement of the thermometers on the sample and the frequency of the lock ins, everything else is kept the same but for some reason the lock ins hits at input overload at different AC gains. Could this be a ground loop issue? I'm not quite sure what else it could be as I'm still trying to familiarize myself with the lock ins. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: I suggest asking this question over at the electronics SE.

Comment: Will do, thanks!